# I cannot open an iCloud account on my device because ‘the maximum number of free accounts have been activated’

Tags: icloud

I cannot open iCloud account on my device. When the Apple ID & password are input, I get this message:

> The maximum number of free accounts have been activated on this iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Is your iPhone second handed? Probably the previous user has used all accounts. All you have to do is setup iCloud on any iPhone or iPad that has not been setup to iCloud or has remaining setup for iCloud and then sign in on blocked device.
I've done this with all my devices and all work fine.

Answer (score -3):

No max number of free accounts are activated

Comment: Could you elaborate if you are saying there is a count on the number of accounts on each device? Or are you intending to [ask] a follow on question.